# Adding a "closeness" estimate to the output of a neural network model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scipy, neural-network

I have a neural network which maps a set of 4 floating-point input parameters to a set of 10 floating point outputs trained on a dataset of ~300 points. The points themselves are intrinsically multi-modal, and there are some sparse areas in the training set that I don't currently have any good way to gather data for (although in real-world deployment they will eventually be encountered).

The data itself trained as-expected during training (test-split loss value was uniformly decreasing during the training, and the errors are all within acceptable levels). So I believe these model is mapping the variables well against each other. However, I'm concerned over how well 'generalized' the model is within areas where it doesn't have training data.

So I'm looking to add an additional output to the model to provide a "closeness" estimate to the training points. My implementation currently is to use scipy to calculate a gauissian KDE from the 4 parameters and then check the points closeness to the training space based on that. Then, in deployment, I return a warning/error if the inputs are too far from the space the model was trained on. This works okay but I have to pass the entire test "X" set around with the model which is a little inconvenient and kludgy.

Is there a way to embed this closeness estimate in the model itself? Or is there any more formalized way to handle this (ex., to give a "confidence" estimate in the model output)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to relook at loss value of your model. At its core, a loss function is a measure of how good your prediction model does in terms of being able to predict the expected outcome(or value). We convert the learning problem into an optimization problem, define a loss function and then optimize the algorithm to minimize the loss function.

> The loss value gives you this closeness estimate between data and
> model output.

This loss value can be accessed in the history object returned while fitting the tensorflow model.

```
>>>history = model.fit(np.arange(100).reshape(5, 20), np.zeros(5),
                    epochs=10, verbose=1)
>>>print(history.history.keys())
dict_keys(['loss'])
```

If you want closeness estimate between two different models, you need KL Divergence(Kullback–Leibler divergence) or relative entropy.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

> KL Divergence is a type of statistical distance: a measure of how one
> probability distribution P is different from a second, reference
> probability distribution Q.A simple interpretation of the KL
> divergence of P from Q is the expected excess surprise from using Q as
> a model when the actual distribution is P.

In the simple case, a relative entropy of 0 indicates that the two distributions in question have identical quantities of information.

KLDivergence is used to distill knowledge of a teacher model into a student model and check if both of them have identical quantities of information.

**Trivia**: *Knowledge distillation is used to compress deep learning model size with little bit compromise in quality.*

KLDivergence can be directly imported in tensorflow as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.losses import KLDivergence
```

You can check a full fledged KD implementation using keras in https://keras.io/examples/vision/knowledge_distillation/

Comment: I just updated my question to state that the loss values are okay and they are uniformly decreasing and behaving normally. But the loss values are calculated based on the test-set, which is from the same dataset with sparsely populated areas, so I don't have a good way to know how well generalized it is outside of the test/train dataset.